# Inserting words from field into new column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, extract, string

Is there any good expression to extract the first word of a field and put it into a new column? I would like to create a new column without the numeric values and filter out words that are doubled.

This is what I intend to achieve

| Input | Desired output |
| --- | --- |
| Gebäude- und Freifläche Land- und Forstwirtschaft 13304 | Gebäude- und Freifläche Land- und Forstwirtschaft |
| Landwirtschaft 26 | Landwirtschaft |
| Gehölz 327 | Gehölz |
| Landwirtschaft 2219 | Landwirtschaft |
| Landwirtschaft 7318 | Landwirtschaft |
| Fließgewässer 37 | Fließgewässer |
| Landwirtschaft 574 | Landwirtschaft |
| Landwirtschaft 6619 | Landwirtschaft |

Here is the attribute table of my layer

[image]

Comment: try this `string_to_array("Nutzung", ' ')[0]`

Comment: Do you really want it in a new *row* or do you mean a *column*?

Comment: True, I ment a new column. The expression from Taras would already work but I found out, that some fields include more than 2 words, so using the space as the operator doesnt work that good. Is there a way to filter out only the number at the end?

Comment: Gebäude- und Freifläche Land- und Forstwirtschaft 13304 or Landwirtschaft 26;Gehölz 327;Landwirtschaft 2219;Landwirtschaft 7318 or Fließgewässer 37;Landwirtschaft 574;Landwirtschaft 6619 and so on.. so filtering the numeric values would be great and if possible the words that are doubled.

Comment: Removing all numeric values would be: ```regexp_replace("Nutzung", '\\d', '')```

Comment: If you edit your initial post with the latter cases and explain what you want (I guess for the first case you want "Gebäude- und Freifläche Land- und Forstwirtschaft" and maybe for the next one "Landwirtschaft, Gehölz" - this is doable in the field calculator but a bit more work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regular expressions to find the first digit, then return the input string from the first character until the character before the first digit using this expression:

```
left("Nutzung", regexp_match("Nutzung", '\\d') - 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

May be:

In the field calculator it seems to work

> substr("Nutzung", 0,  strpos( "Nutzung", ' ')-1)

[image]

Comment: Looking at the desired output in the table of the question, this does not work as intended: input ``Gebäude- und Freifläche Land- und Forstwirtschaft 13304` should return `Gebäude- und Freifläche Land- und Forstwirtschaft` - with your expression, it just returns `Gebäude-`.

Comment: @Babel You have right. But before the post was edited (and the table added), it was desired the extraction of only the first word only